# C++ Map Iterator

Tags: c++

The program just prints the most repeated word. How can I make it if there is no most repeated word to print error or "none"?

> Input: 5 apple apple banana apple banana
>
> Output: apple

I want it to display if lets say

> Input: apple banana
>
> Output: "none"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    using mmap = map<string, int>; mmap freq;

    int n; cin >> n;
    string word;

    if (n < 1 && n > 100000) return 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> word;
        freq[word]++;
    }

    auto iter = max_element(begin(freq), end(freq), []
    (const mmap::value_type& a, const mmap::value_type& b)
    { return a.second < b.second; });

    cout << iter->first << " ";;

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Iterate over the map yourself, and implement the necessary logic. No standard library algorithm does what you want, so you must implement it yourself. Take out a blank sheet of paper and write down your proposed logical solution in brief, short English sentences. Schedule [an appointment with your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) to review your proposed solution. After your rubber duck approves your proposed algorithm, simply take what you've written down and translate it directly into C++. Mission accomplished.

Comment: Walk the map to find the word with the highest frequency.  If this frequency is 0 or 1, display "none".

Comment: @PaulSanders How do you "walk" a map?

Comment: A 'ranged for loop', e.g. `for (auto& map_entry : my_map) { ... }`, will do it

Answer (score 1):

Your use of `std::max_element()` is returning an `iterator` to the first element with the largest `second` value.

You can then use `std::any_of()` or `std::none_of()` to check if there are any remaining elements that have the same `second` value:

```
auto iter = max_element(begin(freq), end(freq), [](const mmap::value_type& a, const mmap::value_type& b) { return a.second < b.second; }); 
if ((iter == end(freq)) || any_of(next(iter), end(freq), [&](const mmap::value_type& a){ return a.second == iter->second; }))
    cout << "none";
else
    cout << iter->first;
```

[Live demo](https://www.ideone.com/qS45YX)

```
auto iter = max_element(begin(freq), end(freq), [](const mmap::value_type& a, const mmap::value_type& b) { return a.second < b.second; }); 
if ((iter != end(freq)) && none_of(next(iter), end(freq), [&](const mmap::value_type& a){ return a.second == iter->second; }))
    cout << iter->first;
else
    cout << "none";
```

[Live demo](https://www.ideone.com/WvQnlI)

Comment: That will not work if you have 2 bananas and 2 apples.

Comment: Yeah, this will not work as @Phil1970 said. Already tried that.

Comment: @RemyLebeau it shouldnt print apple, it should print "none" because there is no max repeated word. Hope you understand.

Comment: "I want it to display if lets say

Input: apple banana

Output: "none"
Thought people would understand from this example. Sorry then.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks, it works. Now I need to see why hackerrank doesnt approve my 2nd Test Case.